# Botones en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy realizando un juego en Python con la librería `pygame`, y quisiera agregar unos botones táctiles en la pantalla de la siguiente manera:

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        touch_x, touch_y = event.pos

        # Verificar si un área específica está siendo tocada
        left_button_pressed = button_left[0] <= touch_x <= button_left[0] + button_size and button_left[1] <= touch_y <= button_left[1] + button_size
        up_button_pressed = button_up[0] <= touch_x <= button_up[0] + button_size and button_up[1] - button_size <= touch_y <= button_up[1]
        right_button_pressed = button_right[0] <= touch_x <= button_right[0] + button_size and button_right[1] <= touch_y <= button_right[1] + button_size
        down_button_pressed = button_down[0] <= touch_x <= button_down[0] + button_size and button_down[1] <= touch_y <= button_down[1] + button_size

        # Aplicar movimiento continuo mientras se mantenga presionado
        if left_button_pressed:
            player_x -= player_speed
        if up_button_pressed:
            player_y -= player_speed
        if right_button_pressed:
            player_x += player_speed
        if down_button_pressed:
            player_y += player_speed
```

Y quiero que el personaje se mueva mientras el botón está pulsado, pero no he podido de ninguna manera, si alguien me podría brindar un ejemplo de como hacerlo mejor, ademas de que quiero conservar que tambien se pueda manejar el personaje con el teclado:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player_x > 0:
    player_x -= player_speed
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player_x < width - player_size:
    player_x += player_speed
if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player_y > 0:
    player_y -= player_speed
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player_y < height - player_size:
    player_y += player_speed
```

Esta parte funciona bien, pero quiero implementar ambas.

Comment: Puedes proporcionar el código entero para poder hacer pruebas por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo, si quieres usar eventos táctiles, considera usar los eventos apropiados para ello, como `pygame.FINGERDOWN` y `pygame.FINGERUP`. Esto te permite manejar entradas *multi-touch* por ejemplo, cosa que no  es posible con los eventos de ratón.

Para detectar cuando un boton se mantiene pulsado puedes hacer uso de los eventos `pygame.FINGERDOWN`/`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` que marcaran cuando el botón es pulsado y de `pygame.FINGERUP`/`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` que te indicaran el final de la pulsación.

Te dejo un ejemplo de esto en acción:

```
import pygame


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return (self.x, self.y)[idx]

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def __len__(self):
        return 2


def sign(p1: Point, p2: Point, p3: Point) -> float:
    return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y)


def is_point_in_triangle(
        point: Point, vert1: Point, vert2: Point, vert3: Point
        ) -> bool:
    d1 = sign(point, vert1, vert2)
    d2 = sign(point, vert2, vert3)
    d3 = sign(point, vert3, vert1)

    return not (
        ((d1 < 0) or (d2 < 0) or (d3 < 0)) and
        ((d1 > 0) or (d2 > 0) or (d3 > 0))
        )


FPS = 60
SCREEN_SIZE = Point(500, 700)
BLACK = 0, 0, 0
TEAL = 0, 128, 128
JELLYFISH = 70, 199,    199
CANTALOUPE = 255, 166, 47

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)

# Jugador
player = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
player.fill(CANTALOUPE)
player_pos = Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 - 20, SCREEN_SIZE.y // 2 - 20)
player_speed = 150

right_btn_is_down = left_btn_is_down = up_btn_is_down = down_btn_is_down = False
up_btn_verts = (
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 - 40, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 160),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 + 40, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 160),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 230)
)
right_btn_verts = (
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 + 45, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 155),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 + 45, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 75),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 + 115, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 115)
)
down_btn_verts = (
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 - 40, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 70),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 + 40, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 70),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2, SCREEN_SIZE.y)
    )
left_btn_verts = (
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 - 45, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 75),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 - 45, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 155),
    Point(SCREEN_SIZE.x // 2 - 115, SCREEN_SIZE.y - 115)
    )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
elapsed = 0.0
touches = {}
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            point = Point(*event.pos)
            touches["mouse"] = point
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            del touches["mouse"]
        elif event.type == pygame.FINGERDOWN:
            point = Point(event.x * SCREEN_SIZE.x, event.y * SCREEN_SIZE.y)
            touches[event.finger_id] = point
        elif event.type == pygame.FINGERUP:
            del touches[event.finger_id]

    right_btn_is_down = left_btn_is_down = up_btn_is_down = down_btn_is_down = False
    for point in touches.values():
        if is_point_in_triangle(point, *up_btn_verts):
            up_btn_is_down = True
        elif is_point_in_triangle(point, *down_btn_verts):
            down_btn_is_down = True
        elif is_point_in_triangle(point, *right_btn_verts):
            right_btn_is_down = True
        elif is_point_in_triangle(point, *left_btn_verts):
            left_btn_is_down = True

    move_vec = pygame.math.Vector2(
        right_btn_is_down - left_btn_is_down,
        down_btn_is_down - up_btn_is_down
        )
    if move_vec.x != 0 or move_vec.y != 0:
        move_vec.scale_to_length(player_speed * elapsed)
        player_pos.x += move_vec.x
        player_pos.y += move_vec.y

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(player, player_pos)

    # Boton arriba
    pygame.draw.polygon(
        screen,
        JELLYFISH if up_btn_is_down else TEAL,
        up_btn_verts
    )

    # Botón derecha
    pygame.draw.polygon(
        screen,
        JELLYFISH if right_btn_is_down else TEAL,
        right_btn_verts
    )

    # Botón abajo
    pygame.draw.polygon(
        screen,
        JELLYFISH if down_btn_is_down else TEAL,
        down_btn_verts
    )

    # Botón izquierda
    pygame.draw.polygon(
        screen,
        JELLYFISH if left_btn_is_down else TEAL,
        left_btn_verts
    )

    pygame.display.flip()
    elapsed = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
```

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es una simplificación de algo que tenia para dar un ejemplo reproducible. Por ejemplo, la clase `Point` era mas compleja y ofrecía otra funcionalidad que no es necesaria para el ejemplo, las dos funciones simplemente sirven para detectar si un punto esta dentro de un triangulo (ver si el click/touch se producen sobre los botones). Lo significativo para tu pregunta esta en:

```
touches = {}
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            point = Point(*event.pos)
            touches["mouse"] = point
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            del touches["mouse"]
        elif event.type == pygame.FINGERDOWN:
            point = Point(event.x * SCREEN_SIZE.x, event.y * SCREEN_SIZE.y)
            touches[event.finger_id] = point
        elif event.type == pygame.FINGERUP:
            del touches[event.finger_id]

    right_btn_is_down = left_btn_is_down = up_btn_is_down = down_btn_is_down = False
    for point in touches.values():
        if is_point_in_triangle(point, *up_btn_verts):
            up_btn_is_down = True
        elif is_point_in_triangle(point, *down_btn_verts):
            down_btn_is_down = True
        elif is_point_in_triangle(point, *right_btn_verts):
            right_btn_is_down = True
        elif is_point_in_triangle(point, *left_btn_verts):
            left_btn_is_down = True
```

Basicamente se usa un diccionario para almacenar cada click o toque tactil cuando se produce un evento `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN/FINGERDOWN`(para los toques se usa como clave el atributo `finger_id`), los valores son simplemnte la posicion donde el evento ha tenido lugar.

Cuando se produce un evento `MOUSEBUTTONUP/FINGERUP` se elimina el aentrada del diccionario.

A continuacion se comprueba si alguno de esos eventos implica que alguno de los botones se ha pulsado detectando la colision entre la posicion del evento y el boton. Si tus botones son rectangulares puedes usar simplemnte [pygame.Rect.collidepoint](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint).

En el caso que quisieras que al retirar el dedo del boton pero sin levantarlo de la pantalla (desplazamiento) el boton dejara de mantenerese pulsado puedes hacer uso del evento `pygame.FINGERMOTION`. Todos los eventos `FINGER*` generados por un toque comparten la misma `finger_id`, por lo que te permite detectar si el toque de ese dedo concreto se desplaza o si termina. Esto tambien permite implementar joysticks.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aun soy nuevo realizando juegos en Python y desconocía totalmente sobre fingerdown y fingerup, ya con esa información investigue un poco más.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Para que tu objeto se mueva siempre que el botón esté pulsado no utilices los eventos de pygame; sino que utiliza

```
pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] # Devuelve True si el mouse está pulsado
```

para verificar si el botón está pulsado y para obtener la posición del mouse

```
pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

El bucle principal quedaría así:

```
def click_move():
    touch_x, touch_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Verificar si un área específica está siendo tocada
    left_button_pressed = button_left[0] <= touch_x <= button_left[0] + button_size and button_left[1] <= touch_y <= button_left[1] + button_size
    up_button_pressed = button_up[0] <= touch_x <= button_up[0] + button_size and button_up[1] - button_size <= touch_y <= button_up[1]
    right_button_pressed = button_right[0] <= touch_x <= button_right[0] + button_size and button_right[1] <= touch_y <= button_right[1] + button_size
    down_button_pressed = button_down[0] <= touch_x <= button_down[0] + button_size and button_down[1] <= touch_y <= button_down[1] + button_size

    # Aplicar movimiento continuo mientras se mantenga presionado
    if left_button_pressed:
        player_x -= player_speed
    if up_button_pressed:
        player_y -= player_speed
    if right_button_pressed:
        player_x += player_speed
    if down_button_pressed:
        player_y += player_speed

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        click_move()
```